# Google search Ajax API more results

Tags: google-ajax-api

According to : http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje
i used this to search on google.
but it returns to me 4 results only.

i need more results , Any ideas ?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

you can add `rsz=[1-8]` to you query. For example: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=gates&rsz=8`